# Байт-счетчик. Работа с памятью на низком уровне в СИ

Tags: c, память

Прошу совета.

Необходимо упаковать последовательность целочисленных переменных. Таким образом чтобы байт-счетчик считал подпоследовательность из не повторяющихся элементов и вставал перед ней и имел положительное значение. А также считал подпоследовательность из одинаковых элементов и вставал перед ней имея отрицательное значение.
Т.е.:

- последовательность из целых не повторяющихся элементов кодируется целым счетчиком (типа int) за которым следуют эти элементы
- последовательность из повторяющихся элементов кодируется отрицательным значением счетчика, за которым следует значение повторяющихся элементов
- нулевое значение целого счетчика обозначает конец последовательности

Пример:

- исходная последовательность:       2 3 3 3 5 2 4 4 4 4 4 8 -6 8
- упакованная последовательность: (1) 2 (-3) 3 (2) 5 2 (-5) 4 (3) 8 -6 8

Comment: Ну, ты определись хотя бы с записью упакованного числа, допустим:
int packed[];
Откуда будет вводиться последовательность? Скорее всего, её упаковку надо будет отделить от ввода данных, путём создания отдельных функций.

Comment: мне нужна функция которая будет упаковывать последовательность, типа такой: void pack(int *p, int A[], int n)

Comment: Да-да. Даже реализация ввода-вывода на консоли у разных систем разная, так что чем функции более абстрогированные тем лучше.

Comment: А, тебе нужен именно прототип функции?

Comment: Я третий день над этой задачей бьюсь. Перепробовал кучу вариантов, но не хватает мозгов решить ее. По этому прошу помощи в реализации

Comment: Хорошо. Я тоже не особо блещу извилинами, но попробую написать прототип...

Comment: Буду очень Вам признателен.

Comment: Один вопрос: каким должно быть число перед последовательностью (в этом вопросе заключенное в скобки)? То, что оно должно быть отрицательным при повторяющемся числе я понял, но от чего оно зависит ещё?

Comment: Это целое число типа int. Оно считает количество повторяющихся элементов. Например в исходной последовательности 33333 , тогда в упакованной будет (-5)3.

Comment: Никто так и не сумел решить задачу...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t pack(const int a[], const size_t len, int a2[])
{
    if (len == 0) return 0;

    int val;         // будет хранить значение предыдущего элемента
    int count1 = 0;  // счётчик повторяющихся элементов
    int count2 = 0;  // счётчик не повторяющихся элементов
    size_t pos = 0;  // позиция для записи в выходной массив

    for (size_t i = len; i-->0; ) { // итерация с конца входного массива

        // предварительная инициализация (выполняется один раз)
        if (i == len - 1) {
            val = a[i]; // запомнить предыдущий элемент
            continue;   // перейти к следующему элементу
        }

        if (val == a[i]) { // если текущий элемент равен предыдущему
            if (count2) { // если ранее были не повторяющиеся элементы 
                // запись и сброс счётчика не повторяющихся элементов                     
                a2[pos++] = count2;
                count2 = 0;
            }
            if (!count1) {
                a2[pos++] = val;
                ++count1;
            }
            ++count1;
        } else { // если текущий элемент не равен предыдущему
            if (count1) { // если уже было несколько повторяющихся элементов
                // запись и сброс счётчика повторяющихся элементов
                a2[pos++] = -count1; 
                count1 = 0;
            } else { // повторяющихся элементов не было                    
                a2[pos++] = val;
                ++count2;
            }
            val = a[i];
        }
    }

    if (count1) {
        a2[pos++] = -count1;
    } else {  
        a2[pos++] = val;
        a2[pos++] = ++count2;
    }

    // reverse array
    for (size_t i = 0, j = pos-1; i < j; ++i, --j) {
        int t = a2[i];
        a2[i] = a2[j];
        a2[j] = t;
    }

    return pos;
}

void print_arr(const int arr[], const size_t len)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    const int a1[] = {2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, -6, 8};
    const size_t len1 = sizeof(a1) / sizeof(*a1);

    print_arr(a1, len1);

    int *a2 = calloc(len1 * 2, sizeof(int));

    if (a2) {
        size_t len2 = pack(a1, len1, a2);

        if (len2 > 0) {
            print_arr(a2, len2);
        }

        free(a2);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Под выходной массив резервируется в 2 раза больше места, чем под входной, чтобы хватило места для самого худшего случая, когда во входном массиве будут чередоваться последовательности одна через одну.

Алгоритм упаковки начинает обрабатывать входной массив с конца, чтобы было проще записывать счётчик, соответственно, в конце, полученный массив разворачивается.

Используется 2 счётчика `count1` и `count2` для повторяющейся и неповторяющейся последовательностей соответственно.

Comment: Все работает. Удивительно!) только не понятно как!  Где проверка на повторяющиеся элементы? Не понимаю как это работает)

Comment: @SergeyZinovev Проверка вот тут: `val == a[i]`. Добавил немного комментариев по коду, остальное додумывайте и смотрите под отладчиком что-куда пишется.

Comment: Отличный пример! От себя могу лишь порекомендовать прояснять для себя код с помощью printf() (особенно если нет возможности использовать дебаггер).

Comment: Решение действительно работает. Но проблема в том, что оно не подходит. Ибо задача должна решатся через указатели и низкоуровневое программирование. Т.е. байт-счетчик должен вставляться в последовательность в нужное место непосредственно через указатель

Comment: @SergeyZinovev Если вам принципиально использовать указатели, то можете переписать выражения вида `a2[pos++] = count2;` как `*(a2 + pos++) = count2;`, ведь массив - это и есть указатель. Доступ к элементам массива через `[ ]` ни что иное, как синтаксический сахар.

Comment: А вашу функцию можно переписать так, чтобы она стала функцией с переменным параметром?  Чтобы результат записывался не в новый массив, а изменился исходный же?

Comment: @SergeyZinovev Этому алгоритму в любом случае нужен временный массив (его можно создать и внутри функции `pack`), сделать упаковку "на месте" он не может. Если использовать исходный массив как результат, то массив может быть не достаточно большим, чтобы вместить упакованный (например, если исходный содержит всего 1 элемент, то в упакованном нужно уже 2 элемента: счётчик + сам элемент). Но если разрешено увеличивать размер исходного массива, то - да, вполне возможно вместо цикла разворачивания упакованного массива (в конце функции `pack`), сделать копирование в исходный.